# Is there an easy way to append one IList<MyType> to another?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Here is some sample code:

```
IList<MyType> myList1=new List<MyType>();
IList<MyType> myList2=new List<MyType>();

// Populate myList1
...
// Add contents of myList1 to myList2
myList2.Add(myList1); // Does not compile
```

How do I add the contents of one list to another - is there a method for this?

Comment: `targetList.AddRange(sourceList);`

Comment: @vulkanino `AddRange` is a method of `List<>`, not `IList<>`.

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant a cast which I didn't specify.

Comment: @vulkanino a cast only works if the runtime type of the object is in fact `List<MyType>` or a derived type.  `IList<MyType>` could refer to an object whose type is `MyType[]`; that would throw an exception.

Comment: of course @phoog, but look at the example he wrote :)

Comment: Why are so many of those answering opposed to using a simple for loop and instead would rather re-create one or more entire lists just so that they can say that they used LINQ and wrote one less line of code.  When did for loops become evil?

Comment: @vulkanino True.  I assumed that the OP's real problem occurs in a context where he can't be sure of the object's run-time type, like a method whose parameters are `IList<MyType>`.   I suspect that this assumption is correct; otherwise he would have accepted hmemcpy's answer rather than JaredPar's

Comment: @phoog, you are correct, and JaredPar's solution which handles the even more basic ICollection is the best (and most efficient) solution for the case of unknown ICollection derived types.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's no great built-in way to do this.  Really what you want is an `AddRange` method but it doesn't exist on the `IList<T>` (or it's hierarchy).  Defining a new extension method though for this is straight forward

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
  foreach (var cur in enumerable) {
    collection.Add(cur);
  }
}

myList2.AddRange(myList1);
```

Comment: I am an upvoter, not a downvoter, but it might be because "it's overkill to declare a method for such a simple task." I received similar criticism for an answer of mine; the method was maybe 5 or 6 lines of code, which saved only a couple of lines of code at the call site.  But the call site was changed to a single expression rather than 2 or 3 statements, and, of course, if the method is used more than a handful of times, there's a net decrease in lines of code.

Comment: @phoog yeah, if i were using it just once I would just inline the `foreach`.  This though is one of the standard extension methods (like `ForEach`) which I just define in every project I write.  They're so incredibly useful.

Comment: I dig this solution even if it adds more lines of code, because the code *at the point of call* will be cleaner. I'm all for clarity at the point of call. And you have to know that once it's written you'll find yourself using it again because it appears in IntelliSense.

Comment: @Tim: That's on IEnumerable<T>, not @IList<T>.

Comment: Again, we're talking about the INTERFACE, not the class. Presumably, he has an **IList<T>**.

Comment: Just curious, why would he use an interface when he is working with two known class types?  Shouldn't he be working with just List<> if he's looking to use the functionality wrapped in that class?

Comment: @RhinoDevX64 I think we've all assumed that in the OP's real code, the implementing type is not known.  Perhaps that assumption was incorrect.  If it *was* incorrect, then you're right, but the fact that the OP accepted JaredPar's answer rather than hmemcpy's suggests that the assumption may well have been correct.

Comment: @phoog What I dont understand is why you would attach a method to an interface, when that method is not unique but replicates a method that is part of a class that already inherits from that interface. besides the fact that his sample demonstrates he is working with two known class types.  as my nieces would say, "whatevs" =\

Comment: @RhinoDevX64 JaredPar's extension method could be applied to any `ICollection<T>`, including `HashSet<T>`, for example.

Comment: As the OP, yes this was just sample code, I wanted something that can deal with an arbitrary IList, or better yet an arbitrary ICollection. JaredPar's solution fits the bill nicely.

Answer (score 16):

If you declare both list types as the concrete `List` instead of `IList`, you can use the `AddRange` method:

```
List<MyType> myList1=new List<MyType>();
List<MyType> myList2=new List<MyType>();

myList2.AddRange(myList1);
```

otherwise you could use LINQ to combine the two:

```
using System.Linq;

IList<MyType> myList1=new List<MyType>();
IList<MyType> myList2=new List<MyType>();

var newList = myList1.Concat(myList2);
```

Comment: Although the LINQ solution looks nice at the point of call, it has the inefficiency of making a new list with the combined items.

Comment: Michael, any way have pros and contras (:

Answer (score 11):

Use Enumerablr extension,

```
myList2=new List<MyType>(myList2.Concat(myList1))
```

BTW, if you do not populate myList2, you can just create it based on myLis1.

**EDIT**

I've try to research perfomance for several cases

1) **AddRange via Add**

```
List2.AddRange(List1);

public static class AddRangeUtils
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        foreach (var cur in enumerable)
        {
            collection.Add(cur);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Concat

```
List2 = new List<TestClass>(List2.Concat(List1))
```

3) **Predefined Collection Count 1**

```
var thirdList = new List<TestClass>(List2.Count + List1.Count);
foreach (var testClass in List1)
{
   thirdList.Add(testClass);
}
foreach (var testClass in List2)
{
   thirdList.Add(testClass);
}
List2 = thirdList;
```

4) **Predefined Collection Count 2**

```
var thirdList = new List<TestClass>(List2.Count + List1.Count);
thirdList.AddRange(List1);
thirdList.AddRange(List2);
List2 = thirdList;
```

Collection's Count is the count of elements for each list, List1 and List2:
And came to such results (with different collection's length)

[image: results for calculation]

Comment: This doesn't add the value to `myList2` though. It instead creates a new `List<T>` value.  This is different than what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Of cource, you need to assign it to myList. Ok, I've modified

Comment: This has horrible time complexity if multiple lists get appended.

Comment: It will a take a lot of time any way, even in case of copy from two arrays into third, or iterating per each item from one list and add via Add method.

Answer (score 1):

#### I used this one line approach:

`Array.ForEach(ilist1.ToArray(), x => ilist2.Add(x));`

Answer (score 0):

If the run-time type of the second list is `List<T>`, you can cast to that type and use the `AddRange()` method.

Otherwise, you have to do it yourself with a loop.  Alternatively, you could use linq to create a new list containing the contents of both source lists.